# Map locations to their nearest location based on latitude and longitude

Tags: java, r, distance, latitude-longitude

I have two set of locations say A(20K locations) and B(2k locations). I want to have a map for all locations in set A to their closest location in set B based on their latitude and longitude.

Is there any solution in java or R.
Java solution preferred.

Comment: I think you have to compute all distances for all points. All other ideas I can think of first need the distance...

Comment: Are these locations in set A and B dynamic in the memory? Or you have them in a database or some? If you need to construct that map memory every time your app is executed it need to be very good in performance. But if it can be only a one time operation and the map can be persisted somewhere it doesn't need to be very optimized. It's simple, for all those locations of set A calculate the minimum distance against those locations in B. It would be from `O(n*n)`

Comment: Plus no one will write it for you. You should do it by yourself and then if you have any problems you must provide a [MCVE] in order to get help.

Answer (score 2):

As from the answer from @rosscova

Take the points, but as a matrix

```
pointsA <- as.matrix(data.frame( lat = c( 10, 12, 20 ), lon = c( 12, 17, 10 ) ))
pointsB <- as.matrix(data.frame( lat = c( 11, 15 ), lon = c( 15, 15 ) ))
```

Then, when dealing with coordinates, you may prefer to use the Great Circle (WGS84 ellipsoid) distance instead of the euclidean. I usually use the **spDists** function from the **sp** package

```
library( sp )
out_Dists <- spDists(x = pointsA, y = pointsB, longlat = TRUE, segments = FALSE, diagonal = FALSE)
```

and at the end using the **apply** function with the **which.min** over the rows to get the nearest **pointB** to **pointA**

```
pointsA[ apply(out_Dists, 1, which.min), ]
```

Comment: Great idea using spDists, much nicer than my solution. I've edited to output the points though, rather than references, which might be more useful on output.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is more useful as the output needed should be a map of locations. Let's wait for the OP reply!

Comment: I have edited again the answer because the returned vector from 'apply(out_Dists, 1, which.min)' will be of length 3 like the data.frame 'pointsA' to which it refers using the MARGIN 1. Instead if you use the margin 2 it would be correct the reference to the df pointsB.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @STaefi in the comments, it's a good idea to show at least a *little* bit of work on your part before asking others to write code for you. Having said that, your problem has piqued my interest enough to grab a few minutes of my time, so here's a method in `R`. Note though that this is only considering distance as a `sqrt(a^2+b^2)` function of the coordinates, which won't be accurate anywhere except at the equator. You'd need to modify this to suit if you need better accuracy there.

Take a small hypothetical dataset:

```
pointsA <- data.frame( lat = c( 10, 12, 20 ), lon = c( 12, 17, 10 ) )
pointsB <- data.frame( lat = c( 11, 15 ), lon = c( 15, 15 ) )
```

Write a function for computing the closest point:

```
closest_point <- function( lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 ) {
    x_dist <- abs( lon1 - lon2 )
    y_dist <- abs( lat1 - lat2 )
    dist <- sqrt( x_dist ^ 2 + y_dist ^ 2 )
    closest <- data.frame( lat = lat2[ which.min( dist ) ],
                           lon = lon2[ which.min( dist ) ] )
    return( closest )
}
```

We can execute that function on a single point from `pointsA`, returning the closest point from `pointsB`:

```
closest_point( pointsA[1,"lat"], pointsA[1,"lon"], pointsB[,"lat"], pointsB[,"lon"] )
#   lat lon
# 1  11  15
```

Or, we can apply it to ALL points from `pointsA`, returning the closest point from `pointsB` for each of the points in `pointsA`

```
closest.points <- lapply( seq_len( nrow( pointsA ) ),
                          function(x) {
                              closest_point( lat1 = pointsA[x,"lat"],
                                             lon1 = pointsA[x,"lon"],
                                             lat2 = pointsB[,"lat"],
                                             lon2 = pointsB[,"lon"] )
                          } )
closest.points <- do.call( rbind, closest.points )
closest.points
#   lat lon
# 1  11  15
# 2  11  15
# 3  15  15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in Java. The math is simplified by converting the latitude and longitude to a normalised vector representation, and noting that the closer the two vectors are the larger their dot product will be (approaching one when they are equal).

This assumes that earth is spherical. If you want "perfect" results you'll need to convert your coordinates using a closer approximation (WGS84, for example).

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class LatLong {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // A random lat/long
        double[] target = randLatLong();
        // Transform to ECEF vector
        double[] targetv = toEcef(target);
        // 2000 random candidates
        List<double[]> b = Stream.generate(LatLong::randLatLong).limit(2000).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // Transform candidates to ECEF representation
        List<double[]> bv = b.stream().map(LatLong::toEcef).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Find the closest candidate to the target
        int i = closest(targetv, bv);

        System.out.println("Closest point to " + target[0] + ", " + target[1] + " is " + b.get(i)[0] + ", " + b.get(i)[1]);
    }

    // index of closest vector to target from list of candidates
    public static int closest(double[] target, List<double[]> candidates) {
        double p = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        int closest = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates.size(); i++) {
            double next = dotProduct(target, candidates.get(i));
            if (next > p) {
                p = next;
                closest = i;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }

    // dot product of two 3vectors
    public static double dotProduct(double[] v1, double[] v2) {
        return v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1] + v1[2] * v2[2];
    }

    // lat/long in degrees to normalised ECEF vector
    public static double[] toEcef(double[] latLong) {
        return toEcef(toRadians(latLong[0]), toRadians(latLong[1]));
    }

    // lat/long in radians to normalised ECEF vector
    public static double[] toEcef(double φ, double λ) {
        return new double[] {cos(φ) * cos(λ), cos(φ) * sin(λ), sin(φ)};
    }

    // A random lat/long
    public static double[] randLatLong() {
        return new double[] {Math.random() * 180 - 90, Math.random() * 360 - 180};
    }
}
```